# Do Elans get the same bonus feat & skill points as humans?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races

I'm starting to play a Elan like described in the Expanded Psionics Handbook. In the description there is this part that says that Elans were humans that got crafted into an Elan at a later point. Because of that an Elan counts as Outsider but does not have Darkvision.

When it comes to starting feats and skillpoints does an Elan get feats and skillpoints like a human or like a non-human PC?

Comment: Elans are aberrations, by the way. Not outsiders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have a full set of Racial Traits and are treated as a race in their own right. They do not inherit any Traits from the Human Race that are not explicitly duplicated.

The text describing their relationship to humans is purely flavour, not rules.

Comment: You might add an explicit "no, they don't get the bonus feat & skill point" just to make it clear.

Comment: He did.  "They do not inherit any Traits from the Human Race that are not explicitly duplicated."